# Can we Inline COPY --from command in multistage build dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a dockerfile which has following stages/layers

```
COPY --from=build /usr/local /usr/local
COPY --from=build /home/platform /home/platform
COPY --from=build /usr/lib /usr/lib
```

here: build is the name of first stage and platform is just the code files.

Is it possible to inline all these copy statements in one so that layer count can be lowered ?

Already tried

```
COPY README.md package.json gulpfile.js __BUILD_NUMBER ./
```

This seems to be working only for copying in single folder.

I want Something like

```
RUN --from build cp -r /usr/local /usr/local/ && \        
    cp -r /home/platform /home/platform/ && \                                      
    cp -r /usr/lib /usr/lib/ \
```

Let me know if there is anything confusing. Thanks in Advance

Comment: its not possible like that. Whats the problem with the individual 3 copy instructions?

Comment: There is no problem with it and it is working fine as well. just that it will increase the docker layers. and thanks for confirming its not possible let me know if you have any docs supporting this. that would really help and it can be a suggestion for future docker commands.

Comment: You might be able to `tar` all the files into an archive file in the build step and then `COPY` that file into the final image. Docker expands tar files that you COPY, so it should work. That's how all the base OS images can create a full image with a single layer. The challenge is to create the tar file so the root directory is `/` but it only contains the files you want.

Comment: seems like we can do this will give it a try. Thanks @HansKilian. Or i can tar the files and once they are available in the last stage will expand it and copy with normal command.

Comment: there is a number of workarounds, but I think youre trying to optimize something that doesnt need it aka premature optimization. Keep it simple. Makes it easier to mainain and understand later when you have to look at it again or someone else.

Comment: Totally agree with your point @TheFool . I was thinking the same just need pointers to convince others that copying in multiple layers is the best way as of now.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to minimize the number of layers, you can copy your final image into a new, 'really final' image based on scratch.

Something like

```
FROM ... as build
...
FROM ... as final
COPY --from=build /usr/local /usr/local
COPY --from=build /home/platform /home/platform
COPY --from=build /usr/lib /usr/lib

FROM scratch as reallyfinal
COPY --from=final / /
```

You'll need to set up any ENTRYPOINT, CMD, ENV etc. in the `reallyfinal` image.

Depending on your use-case it might be worth it or not. Personally, I don't think it's worth it if your only goal is to minimize the number of layers.